# different unix user permission settings within directory

Tags: unix, permissions, file-permissions

Unix user account X is special, in the sense many users can login as user X to create working directories and execute code. The users don't directly login as user X and come through a web interface which carries out the execution of code. They each get a working directory.

I don't want the users to intentionally or by accident view other user's working directory. Is there a way to do this?

I was thinking of creating another unix user Y and putting them in a same group. And have User Y own the working directory leaving user X to create subdirectory under that. I am checking to see if someone has a better idea/solution to this.

Comment: If you only have one user for permissions, you'll need to simulate having more users by adding checks to the web interface instead.

Comment: You might be able to achieve what you want by using `chroot` to give each user a simulation of their own private system.  However, setting up a '`chroot`-jail' is a non-trivial exercise and requires extraordinary care to avoid escapees.